# Why does everything get more expensive as cities grow in density/size?

Tags: macroeconomics, taxation, urban-economics

I have long wondered why groceries, rent, and especially cially taxes increase as cities get larger since the cost per capita goes down, at least according to everything I've read including a summary of Scale:
https://www.wsj.com/articles/how-nature-scales-up-1498239216

I could see the real estate gets priced up due to supply and demand, it's also more efficiently utilized, as denser cities are used 24h per day, and all areas see. To be used as work AND home with restaurants that service business customers during the day  residential at  night and both in morning.

And that doesnt explain higher tax Rates, which see, anecdotally at least to be higher.

Comment: Though another unanswered question asked [Why is poverty worse in larger cities?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/8601/why-is-poverty-worse-in-larger-cities).  In fact it may be easier to be poorer in larger cities than smaller towns because certain basic costs are lower

Comment: You'll need to back up your assertion that "everything get more expensive as cities grow in density/size". If true, that assertion would be a significant new finding.

Comment: Becuase there is a monetary surplus in big cities that drive price up.